# How to reverse a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe as described below. Now I want to reverse the order of column B without hampering the total order of the dataframe. So now the column B has 5,4,3,2,1. I want to change it to 1,2,3,4,5. I don't want to sort as it will hamper the total ordering.

```
A B C 
1 5 6
2 4 8
3 3 5
4 2 5
5 1 3
```

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, post as answer please?

Comment: can anybody explain why -2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can replace just that column:

```
x$B <- rev(x$B)
```

On your data:

```
> x$B <- rev(x$B)
> x
  A B C
1 1 1 6
2 2 2 8
3 3 3 5
4 4 4 5
5 5 5 3
```

`transform` is also handy for this:

```
> transform(x, B = rev(B))
  A B C
1 1 1 6
2 2 2 8
3 3 3 5
4 4 4 5
5 5 5 3
```

This doesn't modify `x` so you need to assign the result to something (perhaps back to `x`).